# Possible to change property attributes at runtime

Tags: matlab, oop

Is it possible to change property attributes at runtime in MATLAB? Consider something like:

```
classdef VideoWriter < handle

  properties (SetAccess = public, GetAccess = public)

    some_prop = 123;

  end

  methods

    function v = lock ()

      magic here which changes SetAccess = private
      for same_prop

    end

end
```

Comment: You cannot change access dynamically. Why not provide methods to access the property and keep the property access private.

Comment: Or alternatively, define a class that holds VideoWritter as an internal property in Composition. Then restrict and control the interface you want to provide as you like.